# Implementation of integral and infinite summation

Tags: matlab, integral

I am having some trouble with implementing the following equation in Matlab:

[image: equation]

The trouble is with using numerical/symbolic variables/implementation.

Can someone please write down the code to help me. Implementation would be great.

The constants for the equation are:

```
m=1; rho=0.5; H=1; I=1877; sigma=20;
```

For example if `N=2`, then:

```
for n=1, An=0.257, Zn-1=inf,    Zn=0.4146; 
for n=2, An=1,     Zn-1=0.4146, Zn=0.1066;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: more details needed, what programming language are you using?

Comment: ok. next step for you - read Matlab basics http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html and try to solve it for yourself! Because people here will not solve it for you they ready to HELP you! So start to solve, show your specific problem and we will help you with pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

In numerical methods all infinite quantities are approximated by finite ones. Therefore, you have to study this expression for convergence (analytically or by means of numerical experiment). Once you know the radius of convergence you know which number to pick up to approximate the sign $\infinity$ in sums and integrals. The numerical evaluation of integrals is a large subject itself (you may read any book on numerical methods or specifically on numerical quadratures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). The simplest numerical approximation of an integral is based on the rectangular rule for a regular uniform grid:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\sum_j f(x_j) \Delta x$$, where $\Delta x = x_{j+1}-x_j$